# SSL Error while connecting to external websites

Tags: python, ssl

I am trying to download Landsat scenes using the library 'landsatxplore' in python using the following code:

```
from landsatxplore.earthexplorer import EarthExplorer

ee = EarthExplorer(username, password)

ee.download(scene_id='LT51960471995178MPS00', output_dir=r'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\landsat')

ee.logout()
```

After running the above code I am getting following error:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ers.cr.usgs.gov', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /login/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1051)')))
```

I am facing the same issue while downloading sentinel scenes too while using the Sentinel Python API.

I am working on a system in which proxy is configured. In the environment variables of my system I have added both HTTP_PROXY & HTTPS_PROXY. Even my '.condarc' file located at "C:\Users\user1" looks like:

```
channels:
  - defaults

show_channel_urls: True
allow_other_channels: True

proxy_servers:
  http: username:password@xx.xx.xx.xx:8080
  https: username:password@xx.xx.xx.xx:8080

ssl_verify: True
```

Kindly let me know what could be the issue and how to solve this problem.